# Git: Fixing invalid merge

Tags: git, merge

A merge on our GIT repo was done incorrectly resulting in files in a state:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        <version>8.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
=======
        <version>7.9.0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
>>>>>>> b99c9817a1a078b3cce7679fb3ba51065d5f86bb
```

Is there a way we can prompt GIT to redo the merge?

Usually we follow the merge process:

```
git checkout myproj-xyz
git merge origin/myproj-newfeature
git mergetool
git status
git difftool --dir-diff 
git commit -m "Merge"
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you pushed your changes to a remote, you better don't do any resetting.

Just find out which files conflicted, fix them and commit on top of the broken merge commit.

EDIT: in order to find out which files conflicted, just re-do the merge.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no commits *after* the merge you want to keep, you can do the following. I am assuming that you were on commit A when you did the merge, and were merging in commit B. I am also assuming that master is what you are merging into:

```
git checkout A -b temp-branch
git merge B
#resolve the conflicts correctly, but do not commit
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "Merging, take 2"
git checkout master
git merge temp-branch
git branch -d temp-branch
```

Now, if there *are* commits after the merge that you want to preserve you will want to cherry-pick them onto master after the above steps.